# DataService query get NULL entries form left join

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataservice

I have a simple SQL Query which I'm trying to translate to linq. But I keep getting

> "...is not supported"

The Query is:

```
SELECT HARDWARE_ID, HWName, HWTyp_FK from T_HARDWARE
left join T_SWInstalled on T_HARDWARE.HARDWARE_ID = T_SWInstalled.SIHardware_FK
and SISWVerzeichnis_FK = 213
where SWInstalled_id is null
```

My try with linq:

```
var cni = from hardware in _context.T_HARDWARE
          where hardware.T_SWInstalled.Where(si => si.SISWVerzeichnis_FK == _softwareId) == null
          select new InstalledOnListItem(hardware.HARDWARE_ID, hardware.HWName);
```

Is this actually only possible with raw SQL? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the syntax for left outer join [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#leftouterjoin). Maybe it helps :)

Comment: @RigertaDemiri that syntax is neither supported when using DataService

Answer (score 0):

Use join syntax:

```
var query =
   from hardware in _context.T_HARDWARE
   join sw in  _context.T_SWInstalled
   on new {
        JoinProperty1 = hardware.HARDWARE_ID,
        JoinProperty2 = sw.SISWVerzeichnis_FK
          }
   equals
      new { 
        JoinProperty1 = sw.SIHardware_FK,
        JoinProperty2 = 213
          }
   where sw.SWInstalled_id == null
   select new InstalledOnListItem(hardware.HARDWARE_ID, hardware.HWName);
```

Comment: join is not supported with DataService. And the `and` keyword is neither recognized.

Comment: Ha, ok, I dont see its DataService...Try use Expand() as detailed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058240/how-can-i-join-data-with-linq-to-entities-and-wcf-data-services and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654915/wcf-data-services-join-query?rq=1

Comment: I replace the 'and' in 'on' condition to objects compare